# Intelligent font viewer for Windows

Tags: windows, fonts

I am looking for a font viewer for Windows 7 which would allow me to view my installed fonts. It should have these features:

Allow to view samples of my chosen text in a grid form for easy comparison

Allow to limit viewed fonts based on characters included in the font. For example in Google Webfonts, I can limit displayed fonts to those  which have "Latin Extended" characters (script). This is exactly what I am interested in, and I'd like to have this filter in my local font viewer for my computer. Currently using standard font viewers I can only display all fonts, and 90% of them are useless because the lack of the extended characters and are only cluttering the preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opcion Font viewer is possibly what you are looking for http://opcion.sourceforge.net/

There is also a review of 25 font management tools here for windows and mac, it is a few years old, but the programs it describes, most are still active so would be a good source for links.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/05/25-font-management-tools-reviewed/

Comment: I installed Opcion but how it would allow me to filter fonts based on Latin characters included in the font?? There is no such option.

Comment: Actually, this Opcion viewer allows me to add my Extended-Latin-enabled fonts to Favourites with such simplicity, that it's ok for me, it's a one-time work to scan all the fonts but is one-click. And it shows non-existent characters as squares and not by replacement characters, which makes it clear.

Comment: good good, glad you got it sorted :-)